# Embeber web https en iframe

Tags: html, aplicación-web

Hay algun problema al poner en una etiqueta  una url ssl es decir que sea https:// , solo si pongo url http es que me visualiza esa web embebida

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te comentaré que por seguridad los browsers ó navegadores (Al menos seguramente en Chrome e Internet Explorer) no permiten esto, ya que seguramente tienes tu iframe en una página http:// y quieres agregar dentro de tu iframe contenido https:// esto se llama ["Active Mixed Content"](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Seguridad/MixedContent/arreglar_web_con_contenido_mixto)

> [La mejor estrategia para evitar mixed content blocking es **servir todo
>   el contenido como HTTPS en vez de por HTTP.**](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Seguridad/MixedContent/arreglar_web_con_contenido_mixto)

Te sugiero cargar tu iframe https:// dentro de una pagina con https://

Comment: Agregaría además verificar si la página que desea agregar en el iframe pertenece al mismo dominio, o tendrá problemas con el mecanismo de `cross-origin resource sharing (CORS)`.

Answer (score 0):

No se si entendí bien tu pregunta, pero como medida de seguridad adicional, también se puede incluir como parámetro el valor `origin` a la dirección URL, especificando el esquema de URL (http: // o https: //) y el dominio de la página host en ese parámetro. A pesar de que esto es opcional, incluirlo protege contra uso malintencionado de terceros que puedan inyectar javascript en tu página pudiendo "secuestrar" el reproductor de YouTube.

Por ejemplo:

```
<iframe id="player" type="text/html" width="640" height="390"
  src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/u1zgFlCw8Aw?enablejsapi=1&origin=http://example.com"
  frameborder="0"></iframe>
```